# Django ORM: Order by dates and weekdays

Tags: mysql, django

I have a table that stores **courses** and one that stores their **dates** and **weekdays**:

```
Course: ID, CourseDates (M2M) 

CourseDate: ID, Date (Date), Weekday (0-6), Full (Boolean)
```

- If its a date, weekday is NULL
- If its a weekday, date is NULL
- Only dates can be set to full (full=True)

**Use case:**

I want to order by the next occurence (date or weekday) that is not full.

**Challenge:**

Weekdays should only be considered if there is no date that is full for that day.

**Example:**

*Course 1*

```
1, Date=2021-02-12, Weekday=NULL, Full=True    
2, Date=NULL, Weekday=4 (Friday), Full=False
```

*Course 2*

```
3, Date=2021-02-13, Weekday=NULL, Full=False
```

**Expected Result:**

- Course 2
- Course 1

**Explanation:**

- Next date for Course 2: **2021-02-13**
- Next date for Course 1: **2021-02-19**
  (because 2021-02-12 is full)

**Question**:

Can this be done using SQL/Django ORM only? Does it even make sense?

**My current attempt** (this wont work in the above example):

```
"""
The subquery annotates all CourseDates with the difference to today, orders them by days left,
and in the main query we only use the first entry, which is the closest CourseDate for this course
"""
subquery = (
        CourseDate
            .objects
            .exclude(full=True)
            .filter(course=OuterRef('id'))
            .filter(Q(date__gt=today_date) | Q(date__isnull=True))
            .annotate(today=Value(today_date, output_field=DateField()))
            .annotate(
                days_until_next=Case(
                    When(weekday__lt=today_weekday, then=6 - today_weekday + F("weekday")),
                    When(Q(weekday__gt=today_weekday)), then=F("weekday") - today_weekday),
                    When(Q(weekday=today_weekday)), then=6),
                    When(Q(date__gt=today_date)), then=(F("date") - F("today")) / one_day_in_microseconds),
                    # the difference is a durationfield, which uses microseconds
                    output_field=IntegerField(),
                )
            )
            .exclude(days_until_next__isnull=True)
            .order_by('days_until_next')
    )
    courses = courses.annotate(days_until_next=Subquery(subquery.values('days_until_next')[:1]))
    courses = courses.annotate(
        nulls_last=Case(
            When(days_until_next__isnull=True, then=Value(1)),
            When(days_until_next__isnull=False, then=Value(0)),
            output_field=IntegerField(),
        )
    )

    courses = courses.order_by("days_until_next")
```

Comment: I'm mystified as to why two tables would both store dates. Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)